# How to pass managed object context to controller which is associated with tab bar controller

Tags: iphone

I have a tab bar controller on my main window.  Each tab is associated with a different view controller and when you click on a tab it sets a different view controller as the selected controller.

My problem is how to pass objects to the view controller e.g. managed context.  Any ideas?

```
- (IBAction)mainMenuButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    if (![myTabBarController.view window]) {
        [self.window addSubview:myTabBarController.view];
    }

    UIViewController *selectedViewController = [myTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]; //I wanted to pass the self.managedObjectContext to the view controller here, I have tried casting but that doesn't work because some of the vc's are navigation controllers.  I have tried using outlets etc.

    [myTabBarController setSelectedViewController:selectedViewController];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply get the `managedObjectContext` from your app delegate in `viewDidLoad` of each view controller.

```
self.managedObjectContext = 
    [(YourAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate managedObjectContext];
```

Comment: I had to cast the returned delegate to my specific app delegate class as it will otherwise complain that there is no instance method for the selector 'managedObjectContext'.

Comment: Right. Forgot to include that.